# How to optimize this simple JOIN+ORDER BY query?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have two mysql tables:

```
/* Table users */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DateRegistered` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/* Table statistics_user */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `statistics_user` (
  `UserId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Sent_Views` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Sent_Winks` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserId`),
  CONSTRAINT `statistics_user_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `users` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Both tables are populated with 10.000 random rows for testing by using the following procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `FillUsersStatistics`(IN `cnt` INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE dt DATE;
DECLARE Winks INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE Views INT DEFAULT 1;

WHILE (i<=cnt) DO
        SET dt = str_to_date(concat(floor(1 + rand() * (9-1)),'-',floor(1 + rand() * (28 -1)),'-','2011'),'%m-%d-%Y');

        INSERT INTO users (Id, DateRegistered) VALUES(i, dt);

        SET Winks = floor(1 + rand() * (30-1));
        SET Views = floor(1 + rand() * (30-1));
        INSERT INTO statistics_user (UserId, Sent_Winks, Sent_Views) VALUES (i, Winks, Views);

     SET i=i+1;
END WHILE;

END//
DELIMITER ;
CALL `FillUsersStatistics`(10000);
```

**The problem:**

When I run the EXPLAIN for this query:

```
SELECT
t1.Id, (Sent_Views + Sent_Winks) / DATEDIFF(NOW(), t1.DateRegistered) as Score
FROM users t1
JOIN  statistics_user t2 ON t2.UserId = t1.Id
ORDER BY Score DESC
```

.. I get this explain:

```
Id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref             rows    extra
1   SIMPLE      t1      ALL     PRIMARY         (NULL)  (NULL)      (NULL)          10037   Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE      t2      eq_ref  PRIMARY         PRIMARY 4           test2.t2.UserId 1
```

The above query gets very slow when both tables have more than 500K rows. I guess it's because of the 'Using temporary; Using filesort' in the explain of the query.

How can the above query be optimized so that it runs faster?

Comment: you are sorting the entire result based on a dynamic property (now())) that cannot be indexed. If you can compute the score when the statistics is updated and maintain an index on the score, you would have a better chance.

Comment: just an idea: If you instead of now(), use a ridiculously long future time (as if you would compute this result, say, in the year 2500), the absolute scores would be different, but the relative order would be kept. So you could maintain a score index that would reflect the ordering you want, and perhaps recompute the real score on the sorted result.

Comment: The real question is: why maintain _two_ tables with (effectively) a 1::1 relation between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm faily sure that the ORDER BY is what's killing you, since it cannot be properly indexed. Here is a workable, if not particularly pretty, solution.

First, let's say you have a column named `Score` for storing a user's current score. Every time a user's `Sent_Views` or `Sent_Winks` changes, modify the `Score` column to match. This could probably be done with a trigger (my experience with triggers is limited), or definitely done in the same code that updates the `Sent_Views` and `Sent_Winks` fields. This change wouldn't need to know the DATEDIFF portion, because it could just divide by the old sum of `Sent_Views + Sent_Winks` and multiply by the new one.

Now you just need to change the `Score` column once per day (if you're not picky about the precise number of hours a user has been registered). This could be done with a script run by a cron job.

Then, just index the `Score` column and SELECT away!

**Note:** edited to remove incorrect first attempt.

Comment: But using to_days() does not give the correct sort order. If we both have 1000 winks and views but I registered yesterday and you 100 days ago, you would get a higher score, but it should be the opposite

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out...apparently my brain was not properly attached. Edited with a possible fix.

Comment: I tried what Chris suggested, but it didn't solve my problem. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Chris, thx for your edit, but can you elaborate more on this: "This change wouldn't need to know the DATEDIFF portion, because it could just divide by the old sum of Sent_Views + Sent_Winks and multiply by the new one.". Maybe I'm missing something out but how could the Score be updated without knowing the DATEDIFF(NOW(), DateRegistered)? Maybe you meant that the Score will be recomputed later with a cron job, which will take into account the DATEDIFF(NOW(), DateRegistered)??

Comment: @user1009456 What I mean, is that every time a user's Views or Winks change, you just have to multiply the existing Score by (new_sum / old_sum). The DATEDIFF portion of the score is only calculated once every 24 hours. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Ok. I solved my problem by adding a Score column to statistics_user and updating it once every 24 hours with a cron job. thx

Answer (score 0):

You should try an inner join, rather than a cartesian product, the next thing you can do is partitioning according to date_registered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm offering my comment as answer:

Establish a future date, far enough to not interfere with your application, say the year 5000. Replace the current date with this future date in your score calculation. The score computation is now for all intents and purposes absolute, and can be computed when updating winks and views (through a stored rocedure or atrigger (does mysql have triggers?)).

Add a `score` column to your `statistics_user` table to store the computed score and define an index on it.

Your SQL can be rewritten as:

```
SELECT
   UserId, score  
FROM
  statistics_user 
ORDER BY score DESC
```

If you need the real score, it is easily computed with just a constant multiplication which could be done afterwards if it interferse with mysql index selection.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you have indexed DateRegistered in Users?